# How to get the swiped cell index path in didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have done `UITableView` cell swipe according to this tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/

Now I want to get the indexpath of that particular cell that swiped inside this delegate

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

How can I get the indexpath of currently swiped Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instance of Your table view by binding outlet from Storyboard to your `.h` file, like

```
@interface SwipeTableViewController : UITableViewController <SWTableViewCellDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *yourTableView;

@end
```

In the same method , you can get `NSIndexPath` with help of cell instance of method.

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
    ....
}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an instance of **UITableView *myTableView**.

```
//Get the IndexPath
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: Thanks :) But I have already accepted one answer and I cant vote up since not having enough reputations

Comment: No worries. He explained it in a better and detailed way!